# Kivy: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a elevator system GUI in python() with kivy. I'm writing it so that when an up-button of a floor is pressed, a function will be called, which will generate a request and send it to the system. I am now trying to bind the function to the up-button using:

```
self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=lambda *args: self.up_pressed(1))
```

However, the compiler sends me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/98742/PycharmProjects/Elevator/main.py", line 122, in <module>
     a_elevator.run()
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "C:/Users/98742/PycharmProjects/Elevator/main.py", line 117, in build
     return ElevatorSystem()
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 131, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 345, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self, ignored_consts=self._kwargs_applied_init)
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 451, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
   File "C:\Users\98742\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 564, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:/Users/98742/PycharmProjects/Elevator/main.py", line 80, in __init__
     self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=lambda *args: self.up_pressed(1))
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'up_button'
```

The ElevatorSystem is an App and contains a FloorSystem object. I've already declared the up_button in .kv file and bound it to an ObjectProperty in .py file, so I don't know why it came out. The core codes are shown below:

```
    # -*-coding:utf-8-*-

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from random import randint
from functools import partial


class ElevatorStatus:
    up = 0
    down = 1
    stop = 2
    pause_up = 3
    pause_down = 4


class FloorRequestStatus:
    up = 0
    down = 1


class Request:
    def __init__(self, start, status, destination, waiting_time):
        self.start = start
        self.status = status
        self.destination = destination
        self.waiting_time = waiting_time


class Elevator(Label):
    current_floor = NumericProperty(0)
    status = ElevatorStatus.stop
    max_carriage = 10
    current_carriage = 0
    able_to_carry_more = True

    def move_to(self, floor_index):
        per_floor = 700 / 20
        anim = Animation(x=160, y=per_floor * floor_index)
        anim.start(self)

    def move(self):
        if self.status == ElevatorStatus.up:
            self.current_floor += 1
        elif self.status == ElevatorStatus.down:
            self.current_floor -= 1


class Floor(GridLayout):
    up_count = NumericProperty(0)
    down_count = NumericProperty(0)
    floor_index = NumericProperty(0)

    up_button = ObjectProperty()
    down_button = ObjectProperty()


class FloorSystem(BoxLayout):
    floor1 = ObjectProperty()
    floor2 = ObjectProperty()
    floor3 = ObjectProperty()
    floor4 = ObjectProperty()

    floors = [floor1, floor2, floor3, floor4]

    request_queue = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloorSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=lambda *args: self.up_pressed(1))

    def generate_destination(self, floor_index, status):
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.up:
            return randint(floor_index + 1, 20)
        if status == FloorRequestStatus.down:
            return randint(0, floor_index - 1)

    def up_pressed(self, floor_index):
        print("Got it!")
        a_request = Request(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.up,
                            self.generate_destination(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.up), 0)
        self.request_queue.append(a_request)

    def down_press(self, floor_index):
        a_request = Request(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.down,
                            self.generate_destination(floor_index, FloorRequestStatus.down), 0)
        self.request_queue.append(a_request)


class ElevatorSystem(BoxLayout):
    elevator1 = ObjectProperty()
    elevator2 = ObjectProperty()
    elevator3 = ObjectProperty()
    elevator4 = ObjectProperty()
    elevator5 = ObjectProperty()

    elevators = [elevator1, elevator2, elevator3, elevator4, elevator5]

    floor_system = ObjectProperty()


class ElevatorSystemApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.fullscreen = False
        Window.size = (1000, 700)
        return ElevatorSystem()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_elevator = ElevatorSystemApp()
    a_elevator.run()
```

And these are the codes in .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Floor@GridLayout>
    floor_index: 0
    up_count: 0
    down_count: 0
    up_button: up_button
    down_button: down_button

    pos: 200,200
    rows: 1
    spacing: 1

    GridLayout:
        size_hint_x: 35
        cols: 1

        Button:
            id: up_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'up'
            on_press: root.up_count+=1

        Button:
            id:down_button
            size_hint_y: 50
            text: 'down'
            on_press: root.down_count += 1

    Label:
        id: floor_label
        size_hint_x: 65
        text: root.label_text
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
        text: str(root.floor_index) + 'F (' + str(root.up_count) + ',' + str(root.down_count) + ')'

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: .3, .5, 1, .4
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos


<FloorSystem>
    floor1: floor1
    floor2: floor2
    floor3: floor3
    floor4: floor4

    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: None, None
    width: 160
    height: 700
    spacing: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor4
        floor_index: 4

    Floor:
        id: floor3
        floor_index: 3

    Floor:
        id: floor2
        floor_index: 2

    Floor:
        id: floor1
        floor_index: 1

<Elevator>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (.7, .5, .3, 1) if (root.status in [2, 3, 4]) else (.3, .5, .7, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: 840/5-5, 700/20
            pos: root.x, self.current_floor * 700 / 20

<ElevatorSystem>
    elevator1: elevator1
    elevator2: elevator2
    elevator3: elevator3
    elevator4: elevator4
    elevator5: elevator5
    floor_system: floor_system

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    spacing:5

    FloorSystem
        id: floor_system


    Elevator:
        id: elevator1

    Elevator:
        id: elevator2

    Elevator:
        id: elevator3

    Elevator:
        id: elevator4

    Elevator:
        id: elevator5
```

Is there a fix to it? Python beginner, so apologies if this is a really simple question.

Comment: **Full** error traceback please. Otherwise it's hard for us to find the source of the error.

Comment: Already updated the full error trace back.

Comment: With what you have posted, there is no problem running it i.e. not able to recreate the problem you have encountered. The trace dump showed that the build method return ElevatorSystem() and it seems that there are missing parts. Please provide codes that we can recreate your problem in order to help you.

Comment: Already updated the full codes of my project.

Answer (score 3):

## Explanation

[Kivy Language](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html)

> Note that the outermost widget applies the kv rules to all its inner
>   widgets before any other rules are applied. This means if an inner
>   widget contains ids, these ids may not be available during the inner
>   widget’s **init** function.

## Solution

### main.py

Use *Clock.schedule_once* to invoke a new event_binding method.

```
class FloorSystem(BoxLayout):
    ...

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloorSystem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.event_binding)

    def event_binding(self, dt):
        self.floor1.up_button.bind(on_press=lambda *args: self.up_pressed(1))
```

### elevatorsystem.kv

[Programming Guide » Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> A class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between < > and followed by :, defines how any instance of that class will be graphically represented:

```
<Floor>:
    ...

<FloorSystem>:
    ...

<Elevator>:
    ...

    FloorSystem:
        ...
```

## Output

[image]